# How do I use render function in vue components SFC?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vite

I have problem create render function in vue sfc components

WLibrary.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">

import {h, useSlots} from "vue"; 

const slots = useSlots(); 

h('div', {}, slots.default);

</script>
```

I use this component in parent component.

My browser shows me an error

> Component is missing template or render function.

Comment: It's already answered : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67918363/how-to-use-render-function-in-script-setup-vue3

Comment: script setup != sfc